# Vue.JS Quiz with score - 2 anwsers work, 3 doens't

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I have a Quiz / survey with a score written in Vue.js.

In this example there is only 1 correct answer, at the end, your score is shown and the redirect takes you to a different page (not included in this demo).

When the question has 3 answers you cannot select the first radio button, it jumps straight to the second one.

What causes this behaviour?

https://codepen.io/bucky208/pen/LMQvxr

```js
// Create a quiz object with a title and questions.
// A question has one or more answer, and one or more is valid.
var quiz = 
 {
  title: 'Reachers',
 questions: [
  {
   text: "Wat stuurt het verkoopgesprek het meest?",
   responses: [
    {text: "De vraag"}, 
    {text: "Het antwoord", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Welke argumenten overtuigen het meest ?",
      responses: [
          {text: "Rationele"}, 
          {text: "Emotionele", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "In een sector met hevige concurrentie tussen evenwaardige leveranciers. Wat zal uiteindelijk het meest de doorslag geven bij de uiteindelijke keuze van de klant?",
        responses: [  
          {text: "Logistie"}, 
          {text: "Contact"}, 
          {text: "Prijs", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "In hoeveel percent van de gevallen is het bezwaar “U bent te duur” ook effectief de oorzaak waarom men niet bij u koopt ?",
        responses: [
          {text: "90%"}, 
          {text: "50%"}, 
          {text: "10%", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Waar hebt u als verkoper het meeste aan ?",
       responses: [
          {text: "U krijgt direct bij aankomst een koffie"}, 
          {text: "Tijdens het gesprek wordt u na enige tijd een koffie aangeboden", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Wat is voor de klant het belangrijkste criterium om u te aanzien als volwaardige gesprekspartner ?",
        responses: [
          {text: "Uw vlotheid en charme"}, 
          {text: "Uw vakkennis"}, 
          {text: "Uw voorbereiding", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Welke klanten hebben voorrang voor elk bedrijf ?",
      responses: [
          {text: "De bestaande klanten"}, 
          {text: "De potentiële klanten", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Hoe kondigt u best prijsverhogingen aan ?",
      responses: [
          {text: "U denkt mee met de klant en onderhandelt"}, 
          {text: "U presenteert ze als voldongen feiten", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
       text: "Bij de aanvang van het verkoopgesprek vertelt de klant dat hij heel tevreden is  van huidige leverancier. Wat doet u ?",
      responses: [  
          {text: "U luistert en gaat er niet op in."}, 
          {text: "U haalt uw argumenten naar boven waarom klanten voor u en uw bedrijf kiezen", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
      text: "Tijdens het verkoopgesprek vertelt de klant dat hij een probleem heeft bij zijn huidige leverancier. Wat doet u ?",
        responses: [
          {text: "U haalt uw eigen argumenten naar boven"}, 
          {text: "U doet niets"}, 
          {text: "U diept het probleem verder uit.", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
        text: "Na verloop van tijd wordt u bevriend met de klant. Deze ontwikkeling is in uw:",
        responses: [
          {text: "Voordeel"}, 
          {text: "Nadeel", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
        text: "Wat is de juiste volgorde waarin u uw presentatie opbouwt ?",
        responses: [
          {text: "1. Uzelf verkopen 2. Uw producten verkopen 3. Uw bedrijf verkopen"}, 
          {text: "1. Uw producten verkopen 2. Uw bedrijf verkopen 3. Uzelf verkopen"}, 
          {text: "1. Uzelf verkopen 2. Uw bedrijf verkopen 3. Uw producten verkopen", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
        text: "Als puntje bij paaltje komt kies ik uiteindelijk voor:",
        responses: [
          {text: "Mijn klant"}, 
          {text: "Mijn bedrijf", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
  {
        text: "Het beste wapen tegen prijsdruk is:",
        responses: [
          {text: "Scherpe prijzen"}, 
          {text: "De relatie met de klant"}, 
          {text: "Argumenten", correct: true},
   ]
  },
  {
        text: "Om projecten te verkopen, met meerdere stakeholder binnen het bedrijf, hanteer ik best de volgende bezoekvolgorde:",
        responses: [
          {text: "Eerst de eigenaar, dan management en tenslotte uitvoerende personeel"}, 
          {text: "Eerst uitvoerend personeel, daarna management en tot slot de eigenaar"}, 
          {text: "Eerst management, daarna de eigenaar en tot slot uitvoerend personeel", correct: true}, 
   ]
  },
 ]
};

/*
var quiz = 
 {
  title: 'Reachers',
 questions: [
  {
   text: "Wat stuurt het verkoopgesprek het meest?",
   responses: [
    {text: "De vraag"}, 
    {text: "Het antwoord", correct: true}, 
   ]
    }
 ]
};
*/
      
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quiz: quiz,
    // Store current question index
    questionIndex: 0,
    show: false,
    // An array initialized with "false" values for each question
    // It means: "did the user answered correctly to the question n?" "no".
    userResponses: Array(quiz.questions.length).fill(false),
  },
  // The view will trigger these methods on click
  methods: {
    checkbutton: function() {
      this.show = true;
    },
    // Go to next question
    next: function() {
      this.questionIndex++;
      this.show = false;
      console.log("next");
      if(this.questionIndex === this.quiz.questions.length) {
        if(this.score() <= 5) {
          window.location = "/score-0-tot-5/";
          console.log("5 of minder");
        } else if(this.score() > 5 && this.score() <= 10) {
          window.location = "/score-5-tot-10/";
          onsole.log("tussen 5 en 10");
        } else if(this.score() > 10) {
          window.location = "/score-10-tot-15/";
          onsole.log("10 of meer");
        }
      }
    },
    // Go to previous question
    prev: function() {
      this.questionIndex--;
    },
    // Return "true" count in userResponses
    score: function() {
      return this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- index is used to check with current question index -->
  <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">
    <!-- Hide all questions, show only the one with index === to current question index -->
    <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
      <h4>{{index+1}}. {{ question.text }}</h4>
      <ol>
        <li v-for="response in question.responses">
          <label>
            <!-- The radio button has three new directives -->
            <!-- v-bind:value sets "value" to "true" if the response is correct -->
            <!-- v-bind:name sets "name" to question index to group answers by question -->
            <!-- v-model creates binding with userResponses -->
            <input type="radio" 
                   v-bind:value="response.correct" 
                   v-bind:name="index" 
                   v-model="userResponses[index]" v-on:click="checkbutton"> {{response.text}}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <!-- The two navigation buttons -->
      <!-- Note: prev is hidden on first question -->
      <button v-if="questionIndex > 0" v-on:click="prev">
        Vorige
      </button>
      <button v-on:click="next" v-show="show">
        Volgende
      </button>
      <button v-on:click="next" v-show="!show" disabled>
        Volgende
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-show="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
    <h2>
    Bedankt voor uw tijd
  </h2>
    <p>
      Uw score is: {{ score() }} / {{ quiz.questions.length }}, we sturen U nu door naar een andere pagina...
    </p>
    
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Kind regards,

Maxim

Answer (score 1):

Because with 3 options you have 2 items with the same value, as you can see in this image:

[image]

Every item in `responses` array should have a different value, so I can suggest you to add another property for it, and use the `correct` property only to check the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, fixed it with `v-bind:value="response.text"`

and

```
score: function() {
      correctCount = 0;
      that = this;
      this.quiz.questions.filter(function(value, i) {
        value.userAnswerCorrect = false;
        value.userAnswer = that.userResponses[i];
        value.responses.filter(function(answer, j) {
          if (answer.correct == true && value.userAnswer == answer.text) {
            correctCount++;
          }
        })
      });
      return correctCount;
    }
```